# INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR windows phone

Tags: cordova, mobile, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I have a problem with plugin org-apache-cordova-file on Windows Phone. I'm trying to download and save a pdf from server. It's downloading it, but windows doesn't save this file. I received a error code 9 (INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR). I turn on all capabilities which was necessary for file storage. Maybe someone have any idea how to solve this problem?

**Edit://** 
I installed app on Android with same code and it works fine on this platform. I think there could be problem with some permissions to save file. On Android I can see app created a folder and inside it I found a file which should download from server.

Comment: What version of MobileFirst are you using ? What is the version of Cordova ?

Comment: MobileFirst 7.1 and Cordova 7.0.1. @Srik

Comment: Share the code you're using from your JS file. If possible, upload your project to a file sharing service & provide the link here.

Comment: This part of code doing all work.
[link](https://pastebin.com/w4SJqVKq)

Comment: There are 5 API calls in the code you've pasted. Can you identify which one of these failed with the error you mention

Comment: writer.write(...) return undefined, and it don't go into writer.onwrite, when I set a writer.onwriteend(evt) and display evt, there I saw this value: error:{ code:9 }.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code (from [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#writeFile) )

```js
function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file write...");
            readFile(fileEntry);
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
        };

        // If data object is not passed in,
        // create a new Blob instead.
        if (!dataObj) {
            dataObj = new Blob(['some file data'], { type: 'text/plain' });
        }

        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}
```

Once you have your fileEntry, call writeFile. It should work on WP8

Comment: I have same code from this site, but in my case it isn't working. I looked for catalog and it isn't there. When I want to save it and then display it by webview I just get a blank page.